# Attempting barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hi I am trying to create a beside barplot but my bars are not in the correct spaces appear to be overlapping.

```
barplot(counts, 
    main ="2011 vs 2016 Men Volunteering",
    ylim=c(0,320000),
    xlab="Age (years)",
    ylab = "Frequancy",
    names.arg = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65-74", "75-84", "84 and over"),
    col=c("red","green"),
    beside=TRUE)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("2011", "2016"), 
       fill = c("red", "green"))
```

Outputting this:

[image]

When in reality I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have tried using ncol = 2 but I can't get it to work, how do I implement it?

Like this,

```
barplot(counts, 
    main ="2011 vs 2016 Men Volunteering",
    ylim=c(0,320000),
    xlab="Age (years)",
    ylab = "Frequancy",
    names.arg = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65-74", "75-84", "84 and over"),
    ncol = 2,
    col=c("red","green"),
    beside=TRUE)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("2011", "2016"), 
       fill = c("red", "green"))
```

Or this?

```
counts <- as.matrix(ELEVENMenVolunteerAge, SIXTEENMenVolunteerAge, ncol = 2)
```

All help appreciated thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it easier for others to help you, it is better to also include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: To be more specific, including the output of `dput(counts)` would improve your question a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no reproducible data for `counts`, I am including few examples on how dodged plots can be created.

---

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```
# Grouped Bar Plot
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

[image]